# Codeigniter page cache not considering inputs?

Tags: php, codeigniter, caching

How can I get CodeIgniter page cache to take inputs into account? For example, say I have a pagination system. With cache enabled, if I go to page 1, then page 2 (same controller)... CI cache will return page 1's content.

```
    function my_controller() {
       $this->output->cache(1);

       $page = $this->input->post("page");
       $data = getData($page);

       $this->load->view('my_view', $data);
   }
```

In the above example, you cannot pan through pages correctly. It will keep loading the cached page even if the posted input changes.

How can I get the cache system to take $_POST data into account and treat those as different requests from a cache point of view?

Answer (score 0):

Caching dynamic content where the view has no noticeable change to the caching class can get messy...

The simplest solution is don't cache dynamic pages, its not really what caching is for anyway, caching is meant for (at least, mostly) static data.

Another way you can do it (depending on result sets) is to use javascript and paginate client side, and use ajax calls to fetch the data from the server, the client would never actually leave the single view and only the initial view would be cached.

How often does the content change? are we talking like a list of orders that changes minute by minute, or a list of products that changes maybe monthly?

If loaded by ajax then just make sure what you are calling is not exposed to your cache (unless the content rarely changes)... As it would be called from a different method this is not difficult to ensure, and on page load you would have it call the first xx number of results fresh every time, but using the benefits of caching for the rest of the view.

Comment: The content would only change every few days, but gets called A LOT. That's why I'm looking for a way to prevent constant processing / db calls. I essentially would love to set an expiry (say 3 days), and any time the controller gets hit with the same inputs, it returns the cached file instead of doing all the work over again

Comment: Are you experiencing issues with slowing down your db server? Remember that database servers do execution plans, etc. so they tend to retain their own cache of those hard hit queries. If you're not experiencing issues, it's simply not worth it. Especially if your queries aren't full of scalars, fetching data is what databases are for

Comment: What database technology are you using? MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQL Server?